# How to move a DIV based on a mouse click in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a testbed with four simple content DIVS which I would like to change the position of when each of them is clicked. Link below.

http://christopherwynne.com/tattoo/

I have performed similar functions with other sites in the past, and I feel like I am missing something fundamental. I am still new to Java, and have always had issues getting anything to work initially.

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery click handlers are not quite right. You're using:

```
$("galleryWrap")
```

but it should actually be

```
$("#galleryWrap")
```

to select the element by its id.

Once you've selected them properly you can do something like [add a class](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) which will attach the left margin of 205 you want.

Likewise you have a few other places where you're not selecting the elements properly. If you try selecting elements with these commands in the console you'll see jQuery can't find them.

An example: a command like `$('div')` selects all `<div>`s on the page, whereas if you wrote `$('#div')` you would select all elements with `id="div"`.